# SQL Server 2012: query to see queries that are consuming more resources

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, optimization, benchmark, query-performance, performance-tuning

I'm trying to find/build a query to show me those queries that are consuming more resources in SQL Server so that I can optimize them or at least have a statistical idea of what is really happening.

For now I'm using these queries:

```
select   
    er.percent_complete
    ,SUBSTRING(text,statement_start_offset/2+1,(CASE
            WHEN statement_end_offset = -1 THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), text)) * 2
            ELSE statement_end_offset
        end - statement_start_offset)/2) AS query_text
    ,se.session_id
    ,se.login_name
    ,se.login_time
    ,er.session_id as 'Vitima'
    ,blocking_session_id as 'Bloqueador'
    ,wait_resource
    ,start_time
    ,er.status,command
    ,db_name(er.database_id) 'Database'
    ,SUSER_NAME(er.user_id) 'Usuario de contexto'
    ,wait_type,wait_time
    ,text
    ,query_plan
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_requests as er
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions as se
        ON er.session_id = se.session_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sql_handle)
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan (plan_handle)
WHERE 
   se.session_id>50 and se.session_id <> @@SPID
```

and

```
SELECT --TOP 10
    SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
        ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
            WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
            ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
        END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1) as vQuery,
    qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
    qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
    qs.total_worker_time,
    qs.last_worker_time,
    qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_execution_time,
    qp.query_plan
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
--ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC -- logical reads
--ORDER BY qs.total_logical_writes DESC -- logical writes
--ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
--ORDER BY last_execution_time DESC
ORDER BY vQuery
```

They show similar info, but from different places and with different attributes.

The problem with both queries is that they seem to show only late queries. I've added comments to my queries that are being listed, and these comments aren't appearing, which means that latest queries (for about 15 minutes) aren't still being listed by them.

I'm ok with seeing historical data, as long as I'm able to control how historical it is. It's good to have a long run view.

But still, sometimes, I need to see the current situation. In example, all of a sudden the server starts to get slow, then I wanna see what exactly is doing it right now.

I'm still googling more queries, but I still didn't find anything better than these 2, to show more current data.

Anybody can give me a tip?

Another question. Regarding SQL Server optimization and possible caching, is it troubling to add a timestamp to each sent query? Since I can't see how old a query is, I'm thinking in adding in each query the date and time it was sent to SQL Server. But I'm afraid that SQL Server will lose the ability to see that the same query is being requested over and over, and think each query is brand new, and thus stop doing any optimization it might be doing.

Comment: I've read those answers. They don't answer mine, because they provide no query that points out which queries are consuming more resources. Unless there would be a way to join sp_who2 (sp_whoisactive wasn't found in my MSSQL 2012 server) to sys.dm_exec_query_stats and sys.dm_exec_sql_text to get the text.

Comment: sp_whoIsActive is a custom script. Download it from here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/tags/who+is+active/default.aspx It's very useful!

Comment: Cool! IDK why, but it returns only empty.

Comment: I managed to find a good query for my need. The suppose duplicate didn't answer it. I was gonna answer my question, but our friends blocked it from being answered. GJ guys, now I have it, but can't share it with anyone need. StackOverflow better and better each day!

Comment: It will only return results if there are other queries running on the server when you run it. That is what you want, correct?